# How can I create multiple groups within a column using SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery

I have a data set that looks like the below

| follower_count |
| --- |
| 5,689 |
| 15,389 |
| 215,869 |
| 53,389 |
| 28,389 |
| 9,389 |

I essentially want to create 3 different groups.

- Group 1: Follower_count between 0-25,000 called micro
- Group 2: Follower_count between 25,001 to 50,0000 called mid
- Group 3: Follower_count between 50,001 - 300,000 called macro

This is the code I have so far

```
SELECT pic.followers_count, AVG(engagement_rate / 1000000) AS avgER
FROM `public_instagram_channels` AS pic
WHERE pic.followers_count BETWEEN 0 and 25000 AS micro, 
      pic.followers_count BETWEEN 25001 and 50,000 AS mid, 
      pic.followers_count BETWEEN 50,001 - 300,000 as macro
GROUP BY micro, mid, macro
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use a `case` expression:

```
select (case when follower_count < 25000 then 'micro'
             when follower_count < 50000 then 'mid'
             when follower_count < 300000 then 'maccro'
             else 'other'
        end) as grp, count(*),
       avg(engagement_rate / 1000000) 
from  `public_instagram_channels` p
group by grp;
```

Comment: Thanks! would i add the engagement rate part after count (*)? Ultimate output would be to see engagement rate by the 3 different groups